# Bottom Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components

I am having trouble implementing bottom drawer as seen in example from:

https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html#bottom-drawer

I have first done something similar to:

https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/

But I don't know how should I anchor it to the bottom. I have tried using different combinations of layout_gravity but either it crashed at the beginning or when trying to open it using:

```
drawer_layout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)
```

I am a  little bit stuck so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `DrawerLayout` only supports drawers on the vertical edges. I'm pretty sure the only thing officially available that would work like that is the "bottom sheet" components; e.g., `BottomSheetDialog`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks mike I'll give it a try. But I don't know why then would write that bottom navigation drawer is just drawer anchored to bottom

Comment: Yeah, that site covers Material design in general, not just Android, so a lot of the terminology used doesn't directly correspond with what we would use for certain things.

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense now .... You can write this to me as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Oh, it's cool. It was just a quick suggestion. Nothing major. :-) You can delete this, if you like, or post an example of your solution in your own answer, when you get it going. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike.M I have came up with solution. I have used [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) to show from menu:

This is just a sample kotlin class

```
class BottomDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_bottomsheet, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): MainBottomDialogFragment {
            return MainBottomDialogFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

And I can style it as I see fit in xml file - so another plus that it's easy and very flexible.